# asp mvc 2 roles and membership

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

i implemented custom role and membersip providers.
and i have question, when user get roles???
i have something like:

```
if (provider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
            }
```

that works.
But then, in some controller, i use:

```
if (!User.IsInRole("user"))
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

and it always false, like user do not have any roles.

so finally, when user gets this roles, and where they are stored????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IsInRole` method queries the [role provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) to determine if the currently logged in user has the role. When you create a new ASP.NET MVC application using the default template it uses a SQL role provider meaning that it stores the roles in the database. So when you create a new user you can assign him roles and when you use `User.IsInRole` it will query the database. Here's a [blog post](http://rtur.net/blog/post/2009/06/03/Quick-and-dirty-role-management-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) which describes in more details.

Comment: thx. in config was enabled="false", changing to true made it work.